# Group the dataframe and check number of unique values in each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have tried

```
df.groupby(['Machine','SLOTID'])['COMPONENT_ID'].unique()
```

The output looks like:

```
Machine  COMPONENT_ID          
LM5      11S02CY382YH1934472901    [N3CP1.CP]
     11S02CY382YH1934620648        [N4CP0.CP]
     11S02CY388YH1934546857        [N2CP0.CP]
     11S02CY388YH1934590637        [N0CP0.CP]
     11S02CY388YH1934591337        [N4CP0.CP]
                                  ...    
M05      11S02CY395YH1934575728    [N5CP1.CP]
     11S02CY395YH1934658824        [N3CP1.CP]
     11S02CY395YH1934662750        [N1CP1.CP]
     11S02CY395YH1934703310        [N5CP1.CP]
     11S02CY395YH1934801982        [N5CP1.CP]
Name: SLOTID, Length: 388, dtype: object
```

As you can see , the SLOTID has only one value in table, but the table is long enough and I want to know whether any group of (Machine,COMPONENT_ID) has more than one value of SLOTID.

Comment: df.groupby(['Machine','COMPONENT_ID')['SLOTID'].nunique()

Comment: Yes I get numbers but the table is too large , I just want to know if there are any group of 2 or more unique slotid. And I want to know those groups as list or so

Comment: df[df.groupby(['Machine','COMPONENT_ID'])['SLOTID'].transform('nunique)>1]

Comment: That was the answer. You could check syntax and repost as answer, I would accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the groupby on the desired columns, use transform on the target column with whatever condition you want.  Using this to slice the original DF will return what you want.

```
df[df.groupby(['Machine','COMPONENT_ID'])['SLOTID'].transform('nunique')>1]
```